# Merging production version into local environment

Tags: craft3, database, environments, docker

My live Craft site was built by another dev a while back just before I joined the company, at the time of launching it I had it setup locally with docker and the most recent site files. Since it has gone live the client has added a tonne of new content and my container was removed (not intentionally be here we are).

Recently I've had to complete some more changes on the site, I've run into an issue where if i pull the most recent version from my production server it cannot be setup locally, the `.env` file requests a load of variables that don't exist. So I've managed to get an older version of the site from the original developers which I can get running, the issue is I can't seem to figure out how to add in the updated site file, web, templates etc. and database into this local version, any help would be greatly appreciated.

The project has no version control on the live one only the older backup from the original devs.

The way I tried adding them to the project was simply by adding in the missing files from the newer project into the old one I had locally then adding in the database as well, but nothing changed on the front end, not sure if I had to run an extra script or something.